# alternatives to pivot very large table pandas

Tags: pandas, pivot, bigdata

I have a dataframe of 25M x 3 cols of format:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d={'ID':['A1','A1','A2','A2','A2'], 'date':['Jan 1','Jan7','Jan4','Jan5','Jan12'],'value':[10,12,3,5,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    ID  date    value
0   A1  Jan 1   10
1   A1  Jan7    12
2   A2  Jan4    3
3   A2  Jan5    5
4   A2  Jan12   2
...
An
```

And want to pivot it using:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b%d')

(df.pivot(index='date', columns='ID',values='value')
   .asfreq('D')
   .interpolate()
   .bfill()
   .reset_index()
)
df.index = df.index.strftime('%b%d')
```

This works for 500k rows

```
df3=(df.iloc[:500000,:].pivot(index='date', columns='ID',values='value')
    .resample('M').mean()
    .interpolate()
    .bfill()
    .reset_index()
)
```

, but when I used my full data set, or >1M rows, it fails with:

```
ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
```

Are there any suggestions on how I can get this to run to completion?

A further computation is performed on the wide table:

```
N=19/df2.iloc[0]
df2.mul(N.tolist(),axis=1).sum(1)
```

Comment: plot 1mm data ?! why ?

Comment: maybe `df['value'] = df['value'].astype('Int64')` will help.

Comment: I believe the error has to do with `An ~17M`, so the fail is due to the number of columns

Comment: I updated the question to show the further computation once the table is pivoted

Comment: Can't you pivot twice and then just `concat` them?

Comment: @rafaelc I was thinking of that, but was hoping there might be a more efficient way. Maybe with datatable...